# Parameter value is getting null in Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I am sending a parameter from html to jsp. When I am trying to get the value in jsp, I am getting null value. What's wrong in my code? Any suggestions please,

The value is printing in java script in alert

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function load()
{
var cal=document.getElementById('course').value;
alert(cal); // Value is printing here
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; // I am gtting response but value is null
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","LoadAjax.jsp",true);
xmlhttp.send("cal="+cal);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv"><h2>Submit</h2></div>
<input type = "text" id = "course" name = "course">
<button type="button" onclick="load()">Change Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

My Jsp code is as follows, I am able to send the response, but the only problem is I am not getting the value

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>

<%
String sn=request.getParameter("cal");
System.out.println(sn);
    %>
    <select class="input_dropdown01" name="ccode" id="Div1" onchange="load();"  >
    <option selected="selected">Select</option>
    <option value="<%out.println(sn);%>" ><%out.println(sn);%></option>
    </select>
    <%
%>
```

Comment: You must use Jquery. It is very easy and ease of coding

Comment: use `<%=sn%>` instead of `<%out.println(sn);%>` that is assignment.

Comment: @Braj Your first expression is invalid , should be `<%=sn%>` instead

Answer (score 3):

I forget set the headers, Now it is working

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","LoadAjax.jsp",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send("cal= "+cal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the URL you are hitting is valid. Use browser dev tool to see what get send.

This works for me:

You have to pull the value accordingly.
I think you can also pass cal in your url as query string

```
var obj = {};
    obj.cal = "Your value here";
    var postBody = "";
    postBody = JSON.stringify(obj);

    var url = "server_url";

    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xmlHttp.send(postBody);


OR
        var url = "server_url";
        xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xmlHttp.send("Your_data_here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use escape function before using it in

> xmlhttp.send("cal="+  escape(cal));

it should be

> xmlhttp.send("cal="+  escape(cal));

as excape  encodes the special characters

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

and server side to decode it use

Server.UrlDecode

http://www.aspsnippets.com/post/2009/02/01/AJAX-Calls-Using-JavaScript-And-XMLHTTP.aspx